# How to modify an existing Linux Kernel module

Tags: linux, ubuntu, module, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am currently using a virtual box with Ubuntu on My Mac to attempt to modify the Linux Kernel Module "timedatectl". More specifically I want to edit the "set-time" module so that it would allow the user to set the time in 24 hour format.

Anything helps.

Comment: checkout the source code, modify it, build and install it ... but you need advanced knowledge with the toolchain (compiler, Makefile, etc.)

Comment: @Pali How do obtain the source code in order to modify, build and install?

Comment: if you really have to ask such basic questions your best option is to start reading books about Linux Programming because your question can't be answered with a simple Stack Overflow answer

Comment: timedatectl is part of systemd and not a Linux Kernel Module. You can get the Ubuntu package source code from the [ubuntu website](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco/+package/systemd). According to its man page, it already supports 24hour formats.

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you, would I have to follow these instructions on the command line in order to obtain/modify the source code?

Comment: @jpatt You can get it from the web site through that link, or if you're running Ubuntu, `apt source systemd` should do it

Comment: @thatotherguy Got it, I am getting the response "You must put some source URIs in your sources.list" How do I add the source into sources.list?

Comment: Please research follow-up questions separately, such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list)

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you, I installed the source code and ran apt source systemd and it succeeded. From now, how can I access the source code in order to modify?

Comment: The "set-time" module already allows the time to be set in these formats: "2012-09-22 16:34:22", "2012-09-22 16:34" (seconds will be set to 0), "2012-09-22" (time will be set to 00:00:00), "16:34:22" (date will be set to today), "16:34" (date will be set to today, seconds will be set to 0).

Comment: Perhaps you want to _display_ the time in 24-hour format? That's a locale issue.

Answer (score -1):

By default, the time in linux machine is set to 24 hour format in UTC timezone. You can use the date command to view the time in your linux machine.